# Confining a swipe gesture to a certain area (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, coordinates, gesture, swipe

I have just managed to implement detection of a swipe gesture for my app. However I would like to confine the area where the gesture is valid. Thinking about this I came up with a possible solution which would be to check whether the start & finish coordinates are within some area. I was just wondering if there's a better or preferred method of doing something like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply create an invisible `UIView` (= with transparent background) and set its frame so it encloses the region you want to detect the gesture into.

Then, simply add a [`UISwipeGestureRecognizer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UISwipeGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to that view, and you are done.

Read the generic [UIGestureRecognizer Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIGestureRecognizer) and [the part of the Event Handling Guide for iOS that talks about `UIGestureRecognizers`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizers/GestureRecognizers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH6-SW1) for more info.

---

*Of course you could also manage the detection of the swipe gesture by yourself using custom code [like explained here in the very same guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/MultitouchEvents/MultitouchEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH3-SW12) but why bother when `UIGestureRecognizers` can manage everything for you?*